# RDP vs VPN connection issues

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

Scenario:

Work laptop connected to home LAN.

From home desktop computer on same lan I can RDP on to that work laptop.

As soon as initiate a call to the company VPN from the work laptop my RDP gets disconnected and I can no longer connect. If I disconnect the VPN I can connect again via RDP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Once you connect through VPN, your work laptop will join your company network and you will not be connected to your local LAN anymore until you disconnect the VPN.

Comment: You've explained what the VPN is doing there, but not answered the question as (a) I'm still clearly on my home network even if I have a secure tunnel to work and (b) internet access to browse the web on my work laptop comes out of my home IP address